# Show that the piecewise function is Riemann integrable and find $\int_{0}^{2} f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

> Show that $f$ is in $\mathscr R[0,1]$ (Riemann integrable) and find$\int_{0}^{2} f$

$f(x)=$
 \begin{cases} 
      1 &  0 \leq x<1 \\
      3 & x=1 \\
      -1 & 1<x \leq2 
   \end{cases}
Here I let $P_n = \{0,1- \frac{1}{n}, 1+ \frac{1}{n}, 2\}$  (the Partition in [0,2].)
Im haveing trouble fiding $U(P,f)$ and $L(P,f)$. would $U(P,f)= \sum 3 \Delta x_i$

But then Im having trouble with what $\Delta x_i$ is. is it $\frac{2}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

A function $f$ is Riemann-Integrable $\iff$ the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ has measure zero.

Points of discontinuity of $f=\{1\}$ which being finite has measure zero.

**Alter:**

Consider the partition $P=\{0< \frac{1}{n}< \frac{2}{n}\dots<\frac{n-2}{n}<\frac{n-1}{n}< 1+\frac{1}{n},< 1+\frac{2}{n}\dots <2 \}$
where $||P||\to 0 \text{as}n\to \infty$

We only consider the  subintervals $[\frac{n-1}{n},1]\text{and}[1,1+\frac{1}{n}]$ since $U(P,f)\text{and}L(P,f)$ remain same in other sub-intervals.

$U(P,f)=3\times \frac{1}{n}+3\times \frac{1}{n}=\frac{6}{n}$ since $f(1)=3$

And $L(P,f)=\frac{1}{n}\times 1+\frac{1}{n}\times (-1)=0\text{since} f(1-\frac{1}{n})=1\text{and}f(1+\frac{1}{n})=-1$

and Hence  $U(P,f)-L(P,f)=\frac{6}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Since $U(P,f)-L(P,f)\to 0$ forall partitions $P\text {with} ||P||\to 0$ so $f$ is $\mathscr R-\text{integrable}$

Comment: In case you are satisfied with the answer and don't have any doubts you can accept it..

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of a lower and upper sum:
$$
L(P,f) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i) \displaystyle\inf_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]} f(x)
$$
$$
U(P,f) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_i) \displaystyle\sup_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]} f(x)
$$
So that $\Delta x_i$ probably means $x_{i+1}-x_{i}$.

Your partition is $\{0,1- \frac 1n,1+\frac 1n,2\}$. In these intervals, the infimums are $1,-1,-1$ respectively (draw the intervals,and check the values).

The supremums are $1,3,-1$.

Meanwhile, the $\Delta x_i$ are $1 - \frac 1n, \frac 2n,1-\frac 1n$ respectively (just do $x_{i+1}-x_i$  and check for yourself).

So the upper and lower sums are:
$$
L(P,f) = 1(1 - \frac 1n) + (-1)(\frac 2n) + (-1)(1-\frac 1n) = \frac {-2}n 
$$
$$
U(P,f) = 1(1-\frac 1n) + 3(\frac 2n) + (-1)(1-\frac 1n) = \frac 6n
$$

Comment: to show $f$ is R-integrable we have to show for  every partition $P$ with $||P||\to 0$ ,but here $||P||$ is not so

Comment: Here $||P||=1-\frac{1}{n}\to 1$

Comment: @learnmore Ok, I have removed the integrability part. The rest is fine, I hopee.

Comment: I don't think it's fine though;unless you take any partition with norm $\to 0$ you are nowhere near ..

Comment: Okay,As you wish

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I know this is old but i am restudyig this. So how did you get the infemums as 1,-1,-1 and supremums as 1,3,-1. I am having trouble seeing this

Comment: The interval $[0,1-\frac 1/n]$ is contained in $[0,1]$ for all $n$, so the function is constant on  this interval, taking the value $1$. So the infimum and supremum of the function on this interval is $1$. Similarly, $[1+\frac 1n, 2]$ is contained in $[0,2]$, where the function is constant with value $-1$, hence the supremum and infimum are both $-1$.Wait for my next comment.

Comment: In the middle range of $[1-\frac 1n,1+\frac 1n]$, three values can be possibly taken: $1$ can be taken in $[1-\frac n,1)$, $-1$ can be taken in $(1,1+\frac 1n]$ and $3$ is taken at the point $1$. In this interval (regardless of the value of $n$) the largest value that the function can possibly take is $3$, so that is the supremum. Similarly, the smallest value that it can possibly take is $-1$, so that is the infimum. If you have still not understood, do come back.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг ok thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @jimmbo You are welcome!